# python's csv.reader in python doesn't seem to actually get any data

Tags: python, csv, sqlite

I'm working on a script that needs to use the csv.reader() a few times in the script.  I use it once early in the script to populate a sqlite3 table with initial primary key data.  I then use it again later to alter the table's data based on what is in the csv (there is a legitimate reason for this order, I promise).

The problem arises the second time around - my sqlite3 table is most definitely populated with the first csv reader, meaning that the first csv.reader() works because that's where the data comes from.  However, when I iterate through it later, there is no data.  It looks like the csv.reader() is totally empty.

Does csv.reader() only allow for one csv.reader() object per script?  I can't imagine that being the situation.

Here's the code that works: (populates my table with initial data)

```
for file in files:
    f = open(file)
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    count = 0
    for row in csv_f:
        #more code
    f.close()
```

Here's the code that doesn't later on in the same script:

```
for file in files:
    print "opening file ", file
    f = open(file)
    csv_n = csv.reader(f)
    count = 0
    thisList = list(csv_n)
```

The type casting the list isn't what's freaking out, right?  I'm seriously at a loss for how to fix this problem.

Comment: do you open your file more than once or do you reuse the `f` handle? because if you're at the end of the file, no wonder why it fails the second time.

Comment: Did you close the file after the first time you opened it? Use `f.close()` after you initially populate the table. Also, using a `with` statement saves you from such errors.

Comment: I reuse the f handle, but I have closed the file each time. At the end of the first iteration, I close the file.  I'll update the example to show that.  And just to make sure that wasn't the problem, I renamed the handle.  The problem is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `list(csv_n)` expression will produce a `list` of the csv rows:

```
>>> import csv
>>> f = open("ooo.csv", "rb")
>>> r = csv.reader(f)
>>> list(r)
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', '3']]
```

It's **not** a "typecast" (hint: there's no such thing as "typecasting" in Python), and will **not** change your "csv" into anything else.

```
>>> r
<_csv.reader object at 0x7f34964b7600>
```

Actually it's *exactly* the same as if you had built the list manually, ie using:

```
>>> lst = []
>>> for row in r:
>>>    lst.append(row)
```

but a bit faster and with less code.

The only side-effect is that - just like with the manual iteration - it will read the whole file, hence setting the file pointer at the end of the file, so trying to reuse the same csv reader (or the file itself) won't work as expected. If you want to re-read the csv, you have to reset the file pointer at the beginning:

```
>>> r.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> f.seek(0)
>>> r.next()
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

So whatever your problem is ("everything is broken" is a totally useless problem description BTW), it is not with using `list(csv_n)` but most probably with not understanding what it does.

NB : you write that

> However, when I iterate through it later, there is no data. It looks like the csv.reader() is totally empty

If you try to iterate over `csv_n` **after** the `thisList = list(csv_n)` line, then **of course** you won't get anything, cf above. Just rewind the file pointer to the start and you'll be ok.